# How to add a seed node in cassandra 3 clutser?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I was trying to change one of my node to a machine with high specs (more memory and CPU). So I run `node decommission` wait to leave the ring, terminate the machine and add a new machine. After that I configured the `cassandra.yaml` with

- `cluster_name`
- `listend_address`
- `rpc_broadcast_address`
- `-seeds`: with the ip's machine

After starting the `cassandra` service, the seed node joined the ring right way and with a low load. Which for me is really strange, since others node took a lot of time to join the ring.

After 1h the seed node is still with the same load.

What should I do to add the seed node?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the short explanation is that seed nodes won't bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many newer users of Cassandra have this idea that a seed node is some mystical master-node equivalent.  It's really not anything special.  Essentially, a node needs to know about the cluster topology at start-time, and the `seeds` property provides a list of nodes that *should* be there.

In theory, you can have a new node designate *any* existing node as its seed node.  And that node could designate another node as its seed node.  And so on, and so on.  All it does is use that node to figure out the cluster topology.

> After starting the cassandra service, the seed node joined the ring right way and with a low load. Which for me is really strange, since others node took a lot of time to join the ring.
>
> After 1h the seed node is still with the same load.
>
> What should I do to add the seed node?

Seed nodes do not stream data.  The extra steps required to get data on to a seed node, are one of the main reasons that it's not a good idea to designate *all* nodes as seed nodes.

You could just run a `nodetool repair` or `rebuild` on the new seed node, and that would stream data to it.  The problem with this approach, is that it will still be accepting requests (and probably failing) while it is streaming data.

The other approach, would be to add the new node while specifying other existing node(s) in that node's `seeds` list.

Once it is up and has streamed data, then you have a couple of options:

1. Leave everything as-is, and any future nodes can use your new node in its seed list.
2. If your other existing nodes have a node(s) in their seed list that don't exist anymore, you can update those to point to your new node as a seed.

The nice part about option #2, is that you can change that in the cassandra.yaml and *not* have to restart them.  This is because the only time you'll ever need that change is when a restart happens anyway.  The seed node designation don't come into play during normal operations.

Hope that helps!